# How do you use weakref or contextlib to close open files?

Tags: python

I have a class that holds a strong reference to an open file. If the code runs without any exceptions then the file is closed correctly, because I explicitly call a method on the class that closes the file. However, if an exception is thrown then, the file is not closed correctly.

Here is a mocked up version of my code:

```
class MyFile(object):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode):
        self._handle = open(filename, mode)

    @classmethod
    def open(cls, filename, mode):
        return MyFile(filename, mode)

    def close(self):
        self._handle.close()

    def __del__(self):
        self.close()

    def writerow(data):
        # Special write
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc_info):
        self.close()
```

Now if I were using this class at the top level of my code I would use a with statement:

```
def get_some_dat():
    return 1

with MyFile.open('foo.txt', 'w') as f:
    # do stuff with f
    data = get_some_data()
    f.writerow(data)
```

However, MyFile is opened indirectly by another object. I know that most Pythonistas will say that I should explicitly close the file, but I would like to make sure that the file is closed when the object is destroyed. The code that I've written will do the trick, but I was wondering if anyone had suggestions on a better way of implementing this behavior.

Comment: No, you are doing it correctly (provided you meant to write `__enter__(self)` instead of `__enter(self)` as your current example stands).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using `weakref` to ensure that the file is closed, even if it is opened without using the `with ...` syntax:

```
import weakref

class FileHandler:
    def __init__(self, dbf, caller = None):
        if caller is not None:
            self._ref = weakref.ref(caller, self.close)
        self.thefile = open(dbf, 'rb')
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, ext_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.close()
    def close(self, *args):
        print('closing file')
        self.thefile.close()

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fh = FileHandler('/tmp/testfile', caller = self)

def autoclosing_file():
    foo = Foo()

def demo_callback():
    with open('/tmp/testfile', 'w'): pass
    autoclosing_file()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo_callback()
```

prints

```
closing file
```

PS: I suspect that this code is not mine, but I've lost any reference to where it comes from. If someone knows, please tell so I can give proper attribution.